# java Class<? extends Entity> how to get instance of Entity

Tags: java, class, entity, bukkit

I have the following code (using minecraft's bukkit EnittyType Enum from: http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/doxygen/d6/d7b/EntityType_8java_source.html):

```
    for (EntityType e : EntityType.values())
    {
        System.out.println("Loading entity: " + e);

        Class<? extends Entity> c = e.getEntityClass();
        Entity en = c; // <-- This does not work and throws an error
        if (en instanceof Monster)
        {
            System.out.println("Monster --> " + e.getEntityClass());

        }

    }
```

I want to get the `Entity` from `Class<? extends Entity>` that way I can check if this particular class is an instanceof a Monster class.

I tried to do `c.newInstance()`, but got many exceptions, such as:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: org.bukkit.entity.Egg
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Are you saying that you're trying to determine the runtime type of `e`? Why not use `instanceof`?

Comment: I tried to use instanceof such as:
`if (c instanceof Monster)`, but got the error:
`Incompatible conditional operand types Class<capture#2-of ? extends Entity> and Monster`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> that way I can check if this particular class is an instanceof a Monster class.
>   ...
>   I am trying to use instanceof such as: `if (c instanceof Monster)`

`c` is a `Class<? extends Entity>`, which is not the same thing as an instance of an `Entity`.

You don't need to construct an `Entity` instance to do this at all. Use [`Class#isAssignableFrom()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29):

```
if (Monster.class.isAssignableFrom(c) {
    System.out.println("Monster --> " + e.getEntityClass());
}
```

Comment: This worked great. Thank you, this is definitely the answer. One quick tweak to your code is I needed to check if c != null, as for EntityType the last type (UNKNOWN) has class null. Other than that this is perfect. Thank you so much!

Comment: Check my comment from above in my OP regarding instanceof. The error I get is: `Incompatible conditional operand types Class<capture#2-of ? extends Entity> and Monster`

Comment: @chrylis the problem with `instanceof` is that the OP has an instance of `Class`, and does not have an instance of `Entity`. Therefore `c instanceof <anything which is not a supertype of Class>` is always `false`.

Comment: Thanks. I read `EntityType` and managed to convert that into an entity instance in my head. Need caffeine.